# Allan variance plot does not match with the true plot

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, imu, allan-deviation

I am trying to simulate an Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) by generating sample noisy gyroscope and accelerometer data. Currently I am analyzing the simulated gyroscope( gyro)
data. Using the noise parameters for generating the gyro data, I computed the analytical expression for the Allan variance as a function of frequency, angle random walk, bias instability and rate random walk. Then I plotted the Allan deviation as a function of time($\tau$).

Then I used the simulated data(i.e. angular velocity, $\omega_i, i=1,\cdots, L$, with noise) to compute the Allan variance as follows:
$\sigma_a^2 = \frac{1}{2\tau^2(L-2n)}\sum_{i=1}^{L-2n}\left(\theta_{i+2n} - 2\theta_{i+n} +\theta_i\right)^2 $, where $\omega_i(\tau) = \frac{\theta_{i+n} - \theta_i}{\tau}$.

I plot $\sigma_a$ as a function of $\tau$.
However, the two plots do not match. The red dashed curve is the plot that was computed using analytical expression and it is correct as it was verified by estimating the noise parameters from this analytical curve. The estimated noise parameters were same as the ones used.

[image]

The blue curve($\sigma_a$)  which is plotted using the simulated data, matches with the truth up to  high frequency region. But it deviates at low frequency region. It is obvious that the deviation starts somewhere near the bias instability region( valley region of the curve) and then it continues thereafter.

Is there any intuitive idea about why the data based curve is diverging from the truth even if both of them use the same noise parameters.